# howto turn otool output into compilable form?

Tags: macos, disassembly, otool

Greetings,
I've created a couple of text files from mac i386 binary (via *otx* and otool -tV ), but when I try to recompile them again, I fail.

I've tried

`cc -x assembler test.s`

But I keep getting this for almost every line :

`test.s:9342:Junk character 48 (0).`

test.s:9342:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 48 (0).

How can I turn otool output to a compilable form ? It is possible?

Thanks in advance for any tips and hints how to do this